Run jenkins job at specified svn version
We have svn repository, now need to build code as particular svn version from dropdown list using jenkins. Please help with this.
I tried to create scripted pipeline and inside it created python script to connect to svn and run job from latest svn revision.
Now need logic to show svn revisions in dropdown list in jenkins pipeline, so user can select required revision and run job.
Thanks

You're looking  for active choice parameters

@MB, thanks for information. But suppose take an example we have pipeline script which will connect to repository and get all checkin details. But for first time we need to build it and then for second run we will get checkin history.
So now it is as good as first time we need to run pipeline to get latest changes and then second time has actual changes in place.
How to avoid this two times run.
Simple we can say at first run itself it should all latest checkin history. Can you please help here ?

Any help here please ?
